# How to show matrix $A$ diagonalizable iff $A^k$ is diagonalizable for $k\ge 2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

In order for a matrix to be diagonalizable, $\dim E_{\lambda i}=$ multiplicity of $\lambda i$. $Ax=\lambda x\implies $ $A^kx={\lambda}^kx$. That's all I know for the question. Could someone give some insight?

Comment: The claim in the title is not true.

Comment: I think he means "iff $A^k$ is diagonalisable for _all_ $k\geq2$", not "for some"

Comment: @Arthur aaah. I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Then, $A$ is not diagonalizable, but $A^k = 0$ for all $k \ge 2$ is.

For the other direction, here is a hint:

$$P^{-1} A^k P = (P^{-1} A P)^k$$

Comment: Note that if $A^k$ ($k\geq 2$ ) is diagonalizable and *nonsingular* (ie $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $A^k$), then $A$ is diagonalizable as well (over $\mathbb C$)  (to prove it, consider a polynomial $P$ with simple roots such that $P(A^k)=0$. You can then build a polynomial with simple roots, say $Q$ such that $Q(A)=0$).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, only one direction holds. Indeed, there are a multitude of matrices for which in fact $A^k$ is already diagonal and $A$ is not diagonalizable. (HINT: consider a nontrivial nilpotent matrix)